How do I get Range.Find to stop at the end of the range?
After defining a range in Word, I'm trying to delete all occurrences of a string within that range. However, the Find function instead continues to the end of the document.
I'll illustrate the problem with a toy example. I set up a Word document containing the following text:
start of range
    a b c d e f
end of range

a b c d e f

And then use this code:
Sub test()

    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = ThisDocument.Content
    
    'Limit the range to between the start and end flags
    r.Find.Execute findtext:="start of range*end of range"
    
    'Delete all instances of "b". Intended to work only within the flags
    Do While r.Find.Execute(findtext:="b", replacewith:="", Wrap:=wdFindStop)
    Loop

End Sub


I want this code to only delete the b inside the flags, but it ends up deleting both despite explicitly defining the Wrap parameter to be wdFindStop. How can I make the Find function stop at the end of r?


.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll replace all instances without looping

Microsoft documentation:

Find.Wrap property (Word)


Find.Execute method (Word)

Sub DelWords()
    Dim searchRng As Range, iEnd As Long
    iEnd = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(4).Range.End
    With ActiveDocument.Range(0, iEnd).Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "b"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop '**
        With .Replacement
            .Text = ""
            .ClearFormatting
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Thanks, wdReplaceAll seems to work. The start/end of word wildcards are irrelevant, but that's my bad for giving a poor example. I'll edit the question to make it more obvious what I wanted

I've updated the code based on your latest sample. .Wrap = wdFindStop works well.
